# Add generic rescue kernel on Gentoo

Tags: boot, software-raid, kernel, gentoo

I have a Gentoo machine (64-bit) with software RAID on boot which was set up previously by someone who optimised the kernel for that machine.

Now I want to shift the disks to a new machine (also 64-bit) but the kernel panics and reboots.  I could pull out the kernel sources and compile one myself, but I thought it good to ask...

Is there an easy (and perhaps Gentoo-like) way to add a generic "rescue" kernel, before shifting the disks to the new machine, so that it can boot the disks regardless of architecture?

*(with software RAID enabled, of course, but I believe that's now default in generic, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
emerge genkernel
genkernel all
```

Now you would get a generic System.map, initramfs and kernel in /boot

Next, add something like this to your grub config:

```
title Genkernel Gentoo Linux
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/kernel root=/dev/ram0 real_root=/dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initramfs
```

Of course adjust the /dev/sda2 and hd0,0 to suit your case... and that should be running on most machines and booting them.